# Count a column based on distinct value of another column pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe like this

```
event_name | id
---------------
hello      | 1
hello      | 2
hello      | 1
world      | 1
hello      | 3
world      | 2
```

I want to count the number of a specific event "hello" based on unique "id". The SQL should look like this

```
SELECT event_name, COUNT(DISTINCT id) as count
FROM table_name
WHERE event_name="hello"
```

```
event_name | count
------------------
hello      | 3
```

So my query should return 3 instead of 4 for "hello" because there are two rows with id "1" for "hello".

How can I do that with pyspark SQL?

Comment: that's just SQL

Comment: Can I do the same query using spark's SQL function instead of writing raw query? That's what I actually asked for.

Comment: But that is not what you show. I will get back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df.groupBy("event_name").agg(F.countDistinct("id")).show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I just need to add .where(F.col("event_name") == "hello") before the groupBy().